# Python Pandas - Drop row based on value

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe with columns A and B

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(10, 2)), columns=list('AB'))
```

I create column C, which is NULL if `A > B`

```
df['C'] = np.select([ df.A > df.B ], [df.A], default=np.NaN)
```

That gives:

```
    A   B     C
0  95  19  95.0
1  46  11  46.0
2  96  86  96.0
3  22  61   NaN
4  69   1  69.0
5  78  91   NaN
6  42   7  42.0
7  24  28   NaN
8  55  92   NaN
9  92  16  92.0
```

I then drop rows that have df.C as NaN with one of several methods:

```
df = df.dropna(subset=['C'], how='any')
```

or

```
df = df.drop(df[pd.isnull(df.C)].index)
```

or

```
df = df.drop(df[(pd.isnull(df.C))].index)
```

and all 3 methods give me roughly have the rows. In this case:

```
    A   B     C
0  95  19  95.0
1  46  11  46.0
2  96  86  96.0
4  69   1  69.0
6  42   7  42.0
9  92  16  92.0
```

But when I don't use a number, for example a string:

```
df['C'] = np.select([ df.A > df.B ], ['yes'], default=np.NaN)
```

Then those same 3 methods to drop rows with df.C being NaN are not filtered. For example, when `df.A > df.B` sets column C to `yes`, I get something like this:

```
    A   B    C
0   6  70  nan
1  85  46  yes
2  76  87  nan
3  77  36  yes
4  73  18  yes
5   1  41  nan
6  19  69  nan
7  62  89  nan
8   6   7  nan
9  35  75  nan
```

I can fix this, by replacing pd.NaN with a string like 'IGNORE', and then filtering 'IGNORE', but I find this result otherwise unexpected.

```
df['C'] = np.select([ df.A > df.B ], ['yes'], default='IGNORE')
df = df.drop(df[(df.C == 'IGNORE')].index)
```

**What's going on here? (When df.C is a string, are my pd.NaN's being converted to strings?)**

---

I'm using 64 bit Python 2.7.13, Pandas 0.19.2, and Numpy 1.11.3 on Windows 10.

Comment: @Psidom Yes, true. It seems NaN is literally "not a number" and is being converted to a string "nan".

Comment: @Psidom if you write your comment as an answer I'd be happy to accept it. It doesn't really explain why, but it definitely solves the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your case is similar to this one:

```
np.array([1,2,'3',np.nan])
# array(['1', '2', '3', 'nan'], 
#       dtype='<U21')
```

since `np.select` also returns an array, if you further check

```
type(np.nan)
# float

str(np.nan)
# 'nan'
```

so `np.nan` is a float, but numpy array prefers single data type except for [structured array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html), so when there is a string element in the array, all elements are converted to string.

---

For your case, if you have string column, you can use `None` in place of `np.nan` as default, this will create a missing value which can pass `isnull()` check and works with `dropna()` :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
​
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(10, 2)), columns=list('AB'))
df['C'] = np.select([ df.A > df.B ], ['yes'], default=None)

df.dropna()

#    A  B     C
#0  82  1   yes
#3  84  8   yes
#6  52  30  yes
#7  68  61  yes
#9  91  87  yes
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of dropping, take only finite values.

```
df = df[np.isfinite(df['C'])]
```

Edit:

As per you comment `nan` is of the type `string`, so, remove rows based on values:

`df = df[df.C != "nan"]` will work

```
df[df.C.notnull()]
    A   B    C
0  67  23  yes
1  91  61  yes
2  30  92  nan
3  53  97  nan
4  81  11  yes
5  23   7  yes
6  47  39  yes
7  11  27  nan
8  46  55  nan
9  31  82  nan
df = df[df.C != "nan"]


    A   B    C
0  67  23  yes
1  91  61  yes
4  81  11  yes
5  23   7  yes
6  47  39  yes
```

Comment: I get a TypeError `ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''`

Comment: I have tried to just simulate your problemand came up with this solution.  import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(10, 2)), columns=list('AB'))
 df['C'] = np.select([ df.A > df.B ], [df.A], default=np.NaN)
 print df
    A   B     C
0  81  17  81.0
1  14  67   NaN
2  16   9  16.0
3  25  31   NaN
4  35  36   NaN
5  56   5  56.0
6  18  20   NaN
7  32   4  32.0
8  46  51   NaN
9  53  34  53.0 df = df[np.isfinite(df['C'])]
 print df
    A   B     C
0  81  17  81.0
2  16   9  16.0
5  56   5  56.0
7  32   4  32.0
9  53  34  53.0

Comment: Ok the difference is that in my actual code (and not the sample code I posted here), please try this: `df['C'] = np.select([ df.A > df.B ], [u'yes'], default=np.NaN)`